# List of data.frame manipulation and combination generation

Tags: r, list, sorting, dataframe

Title isn't the best, but this is a complex task to explain in a single sentence. I'm working on dynamically generating three lists of dataframes where each element in all of the lists correspond to each other within the same order of the list. Such as L1[[1]], L2[[1]], L3[[1]], representing data that is related to each other, etc. I've been working on this for about 35 hours and cannot figure out a simplified way to make this work.

There are two main sources of data, what I'm calling "sort" and "ref" for sorting and reference.

This is a very simplified version of the reference data. The actual data comes from multiple .csv files. This data can contain n number of rows with static column names where the ID represents the ID of the row, and each column represents a variable. The R appended represents the "right" and the lack of R represents the "left":

```
R1 <- c(1,200,201,20,21,300,301,30,31,400,401,40,41)
R2 <- c(2,201,202,21,22,301,302,31,32,401,402,41,42)
R3 <- c(3,200,201,20,21,300,301,30,31,NA,NA,NA,NA)
R4 <- c(4,201,202,21,22,NA,NA,NA,NA,401,402,41,42)
ref <- data.frame(rbind(R1,R2,R3,R4))
colnames(ref) <- c("ID","H1","H1R","H2","H2R","U1","U1R","U2","U2R","R1","R1R","R2","R2R")
```

The sort data is similar but formatted differently. It has corresponding column names with the exception that R is not appended but listed separately in a different side column:

```
R1 <- c(1,"left","H",1,200,20,NA,NA,NA,NA)
R2 <- c(2,"right","H",2,201,21,NA,NA,NA,NA)
R3 <- c(3,"left","R",2,NA,NA,NA,NA,400,40)
R4 <- c(4,"right","R",3,NA,NA,NA,NA,401,41)
R5 <- c(5,"left","U",2,NA,NA,300,30,NA,NA)
R6 <- c(6,"right","U",5,NA,NA,301,31,NA,NA)
sort <- data.frame(rbind(R1,R2,R3,R4,R5,R6))
colnames(sort) <- c("ID","Side","Element","Individual","H1","H2","U1","U2","R1","R2")
```

The code I'm trying to develop will use two additional objects of element names. The first can contain any number of elements whereas the second always contains one element. These correspond to the "Element" variable in both the sort and reference data. Example:

```
B1 <- c("H","U")
B2 <- "R"
```

The first task is to split the sort data by B1 and B2 using the following code:

```
sort1 <- array()
for (i in B1) {
    sort1 <- rbind(sort1, sort[sort$Element == i,])
}
sort1 <- sort1[-1,] #removes first row from binding NA row
sort2 <- sort[sort$Element == B2,]
```

Now sort1 and sort2. The next task is to group sort1 by the same Individual numbers using the following code:

```
a1 <- list(data.frame())
j <- 1
for (i in unique(sort1$Individual)) {
    a1[[j]] <- sort1[sort1$Individual == i,]
    j <- j + 1
}
sort1 <- a1
```

Now at this stage we have a list, sort1, which contains data frames of rows that had the same Individual number. Sort2, which contains the elements that will only contain a single row, and ref, which contains references for all variables. Now I need to create unique combinations between sort1 and sort2 where every single data frame in sort1 has a combination with sort2, as long as the side and element in sort2 are not present in sort1 using the following code:

```
a1 <- list(data.frame())
a2 <- list(data.frame())
x <- 1  
for(i in 1:length(sort1)) {
    for(j in 1:nrow(sort2)) {
        if(sort1[[i]]$Element != sort2[j,]$Element || sort1[[i]]$Side != sort2[j,]$Side) {
            a1[[x]] <- sort1[[i]][,colSums(is.na(sort1[[i]])) < nrow(sort1[[i]])] #removes NAs
            a2[[x]] <- sort2[j,][,colSums(is.na(sort2[j,])) < nrow(sort2[j,])] #removes NAs
        }
        x <- x + 1
    }
}
```

Now a1 and a2 are both lists which contain corresponding combinations where each index of the list correspond to each other. So a1[[1]] corresponds to a2[[1]] and so on.

All of this code works up to this point. Now what I need to do is create a list of reference data, similar to how I split up the sort data. The criteria for reference is as follows. The ID from reference must be the SAME across all variables for each combination (IE each a1[[1]], a2[[2]]) meaning there cannot be any NAs in the reference data for each unique combination.

For example, for a1[[4]] and a2[[4]] I need to pull the reference data corresponding to the side and reference data available.

```
a1[[4]]:
ID  Side   Element Individual   H1   H2   U1   U2
2   right     H        2        201   21 <NA> <NA>
5   left      U        2       <NA> <NA>  300  30

a2[[4]]:
ID  Side    Element Individual  R1 R2
4   right       R       3      401 41
```

and I need a3[[4]] to look like this where no NAs are present, and each variable has data available for that single ID. At this point all three lists of data.frames have corresponding data.:

```
ID    H1R   H2R  U1    U2    R1R   R2R  
1     201,  21,  300,  30,   401,  41
2     202,  22,  301,  31,   402,  42
```

The following code is my attempt at this, but it's currently broken and horribly designed:

```
zz <- 1
REF1 <- list(data.frame())
myfun <- function(x,y) {
    names1 <- colnames(x[5:ncol(x)])
    names2 <- colnames(y[5:ncol(y)])
    names <- c(names1, names2)

    IND1 <- data.frame()
    IND2 <- data.frame()
    for(n in names1) {
        for(i in nrow(x)) {
            if(x[i,]$Side == "left") {
                if(!is.na(x[i,][[n]])) {
                    name <- n
                    IND1[zz] <- ref[[x[i,]$Element]][[name]]
                }
            }
            if(x[i,]$Side == "right") {
                if(!is.na(x[i,][[n]])) {
                    name <- paste(n, "R", sep="")
                    IND2[zz] <- ref[[x[i,]$Element]][[name]]
                }
            }
        }
    }
    DEP1 <- data.frame()
    DEP2 <- data.frame()
    for(n in names2) {
        if(y$Side == "left") {
            if(!is.na(y[[n]])) {
                name <- n
                DEP1[zz] <- ref[[y$Element]][[name]]
            }
        }
        if(y$Side == "right") {
            if(!is.na(y[[n]])) {
                name <- paste(n, "R", sep="")
                DEP2[zz] <- ref[[y$Element]][[name]]
            }
        }
    }#names

    REF1[[zz]] <- cbind(IND1, IND2, DEP1, DEP2)
    zz <- zz + 1
    return(REF1)
}#myfun
output1 <- mapply(myfun, x = a1, y = a2)
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I'm pulling my hair out trying to simplify this. Let me know if I need to clarify anything! The end goal is to have three lists of data frames to be used in various statistical tests where each index of each list represents a single combination including the reference data to be used.

EDITED: Even though the column names are static for the variables I can't specify them directly in the code as they may or may not be used (with the exception of ID, Side, Element, and Individual). In reality I have as many as 185 different variables with the full set of data.

EDITED: Here are the desired combinations for the sort data. Not in any particular dataframe but merely a visual representation the combinations.

```
[[1]]
   ID Side Element Individual  H1 H2                  ID Side Element Individual  R1 R2
    1 left       H          1 200 20                   3 left       R          2 400 40


[[2]]
   ID Side Element Individual  H1 H2                  ID  Side Element Individual  R1 R2
    1 left       H          1 200 20                   4 right       R          3 401 41


[[3]]
   ID  Side Element Individual   H1   H2   U1   U2    ID Side Element Individual  R1 R2
    2 right       H          2  201   21 <NA> <NA>     3 left       R          2 400 40
    5  left       U          2 <NA> <NA>  300   30     


[[4]]
   ID  Side Element Individual   H1   H2   U1   U2    ID  Side Element Individual  R1 R2
    2 right       H          2  201   21 <NA> <NA>     4 right       R          3 401 41
    5  left       U          2 <NA> <NA>  300   30  


[[5]]
   ID  Side Element Individual  U1 U2                 ID Side Element Individual  R1 R2
   6 right       U          5 301 31                   3 left       R          2 400 40


[[6]]
   ID  Side Element Individual  U1 U2                 ID  Side Element Individual  R1 R2
   6 right       U          5 301 31                   4 right       R          3 401 41
```

Answer (score 0):

#### NOTE: this isn't a solution, but im thinking you could use to help guide or clarify for me a bit more what we're trying to achieve here as there may be a simpler approach. I've been in the 35 hour-head-pounding scenario trying to jam the square peg before so I get it. Code so far does the following:

1. Splits the dataset for `sort` into a list of data.frames
2. Splits once more the data frames based on B1,B2 sort1 list of data.frames

   ```
   f <- function(x_tbl){
    x_tbl %>% (function(x){
    # find string occurances of "H|U" in Element column and filter
    a <- x %>% filter(grepl(paste0(B1, collapse = "|"), Element))
    # filter sort table where the element is "R"
    b <- x[x$Element == B2,]
    # combine into list
    new_split <- list(a,b)
    # naming just so I can follow allong here
    names(new_split) <- c('sort1','sort2')
    # Splitting the sort1 table again, now by the Individual column
    new_split[['sort1']] <- split(
    new_split[['sort1']], new_split[['sort1']][['Individual']])
    # Now have the list of variable tables and key tables...
    # not sure what you're trying to say after this point
     return(new_split)
    })
   }
   ```

### Running on the sort table gets me here... now help me out

```
> f(sort)
$sort1
$sort1$`1`
  ID Side Element Individual  H1 H2   U1   U2   R1   R2
1  1 left       H          1 200 20 <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA>

$sort1$`2`
  ID  Side Element Individual   H1   H2   U1   U2   R1   R2
2  2 right       H          2  201   21 <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA>
3  5  left       U          2 <NA> <NA>  300   30 <NA> <NA>

$sort1$`5`
  ID  Side Element Individual   H1   H2  U1 U2   R1   R2
4  6 right       U          5 <NA> <NA> 301 31 <NA> <NA>


$sort2
   ID  Side Element Individual   H1   H2   U1   U2  R1 R2
R3  3  left       R          2 <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> 400 40
R4  4 right       R          3 <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> 401 41
```

## EDIT ATTEMPT #1 I also put the code at this gist:

https://gist.github.com/CarlBoneri/edd9ad9c89fdbf81a5ad87532228a8b0

```
library(dplyr)
library(jsonlite)
#' Given the data frame `sort`,
#' and privided variables of: `B1` and `B2` wherby `B1` represents an array
#' of `Elements` to be matched and compared against from table `sort` given
#' the outlying variable input of `B2` to find all unique pair-values of
#' column vectors `H1:R2`
#'
#'
#' ## TARGET ELEMENTS
#' 1) Split the sort table into grouped tables, each returned item in the list
#'    representing a unique `Element` variable from input `B1`
#'
# Setup by filtering matches of input `B1`
target_chunk <- sort[grepl(paste0(B1,collapse="|"),sort$Element),]
target_chunk
===  =====  =======  ==========  ===  ===  ===  ===  ===  ===
ID   Side   Element  Individual  H1   H2   U1   U2   R1   R2 
===  =====  =======  ==========  ===  ===  ===  ===  ===  ===
1    left   H        1           200  20   NA   NA   NA   NA 
2    right  H        2           201  21   NA   NA   NA   NA 
5    left   U        2           NA   NA   300  30   NA   NA 
6    right  U        5           NA   NA   301  31   NA   NA 
===  =====  =======  ==========  ===  ===  ===  ===  ===  ===


# Split on the individual
target_list_ind <- split(target_chunk, target_chunk$Individual)
target_list_ind
$`1`
ID Side Element Individual  H1 H2   U1   U2   R1   R2
R1  1 left       H          1 200 20 <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA>

$`2`
   ID  Side Element Individual   H1   H2   U1   U2   R1   R2
R2  2 right       H          2  201   21 <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA>
R5  5  left       U          2 <NA> <NA>  300   30 <NA> <NA>

$`5`
   ID  Side Element Individual   H1   H2  U1 U2   R1   R2
R6  6 right       U          5 <NA> <NA> 301 31 <NA> <NA>
```

---

```
# Split each iteration of the `target_list_ind` on the Element
target_list_elm <- sapply(target_list_ind, function(i){
  if(nrow(i)>1){
    split(i, i[['Element']])
  }else{
    i
  }
})
target_list_elm

> target_list_elm
$`1`
   ID Side Element Individual  H1 H2   U1   U2   R1   R2
R1  1 left       H          1 200 20 <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA>

$`2`
$`2`$H
   ID  Side Element Individual  H1 H2   U1   U2   R1   R2
R2  2 right       H          2 201 21 <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA>

$`2`$U
   ID Side Element Individual   H1   H2  U1 U2   R1   R2
R5  5 left       U          2 <NA> <NA> 300 30 <NA> <NA>


$`5`
   ID  Side Element Individual   H1   H2  U1 U2   R1   R2
R6  6 right       U          5 <NA> <NA> 301 31 <NA> <NA>

#' 2) Set up our inner key table that represents the `B2` variable
source_tbl <- sort[grepl(paste0(B2),sort$Element),]
```

---

```
#' 3) The big loop here.. not sure if the result is what you are referencing
#'
element_l_df <- lapply(target_list_elm, function(i){
  if(is.data.frame(i)){
    f_src <- source_tbl[i[['Side']] != source_tbl$Side,]
    f_src <- f_src[i[['Element']] != f_src$Element,]
    source_el <- f_src[['Element']]
    target_el <- i
    source_vals <- f_src %>% select(-c(ID, Individual,Element,Side))
    target_vals <- i%>%select(-c(ID, Individual,Element,Side))
    var_bound <- cbind(source_vals[!mapply(is.na, source_vals)],
                       target_vals[!mapply(is.na, target_vals)])
    data.frame(individual = target_el[['Individual']],
               source_element = source_el,
               target_element = target_el[['Element']],
               as.data.frame(var_bound))


  }else{
    ldply(1:length(i), function(x){
      f_src <- source_tbl[i[[x]][['Side']] != source_tbl$Side,]
      f_src <- f_src[i[[x]][['Element']] != f_src$Element,]
      source_el <- f_src[['Element']]
      target_el <- i[[x]]
      target_vals <- i[[x]]%>%select(-c(ID, Individual,Element,Side))
      source_vals <- f_src %>% select(-c(ID, Individual,Element,Side))
      var_bound <- data.frame(source_vals[!mapply(is.na, source_vals)],
                              target_vals[!mapply(is.na, target_vals)])
      data.frame(individual = target_el[['Individual']],
                 source_element = source_el,
                 target_element = target_el[['Element']],
                 as.data.frame(var_bound))


    })
  }
})

element_l_df
```

---

#### Potential result:

```
#' rbind.pages to put into 1 data frame
#'
rbind.pages(element_l_df)

==========  ==============  ==============  ===  ===  ===  ===  ===  ===
individual  source_element  target_element  R1   R2   H1   H2   U1   U2 
==========  ==============  ==============  ===  ===  ===  ===  ===  ===
1           R               H               401  41   200  20   NA   NA 
2           R               H               400  40   201  21   NA   NA 
2           R               U               401  41   NA   NA   300  30 
5           R               U               400  40   NA   NA   301  31 
==========  ==============  ==============  ===  ===  ===  ===  ===  ===
```

## Edit 2

```
A <- melt(rbind.pages(element_l_df), c("source_element","target_element", "individual"))
> head(A)
  source_element target_element individual variable value
1              R              H          1       R1   401
2              R              H          2       R1   400
3              R              U          2       R1   401
4              R              U          5       R1   400
5              R              H          1       R2    41
6              R              H          2       R2    40
```

#### Is that the result you were after?

## comment on edit

[image: Okay this was the model, ill circle back on this tom]

Comment: I'm not able to get your code working, but I think I see what you are getting at. Might be easier to explain what I'm doing at the end of all of this. I want to compare the elements in sort1 to every element in sort2 as long as the 'side' and 'element' in sort2 are not the same as an element in sort1. For each comparison I'll be running multivariate adaptive regression splines between the variables in sort1 and the variables in sort2. That's why in the code that I do have working, if you type a1[[1]] and a2[[1]], that will be one comparison, a2[[2]] and a2[[2]] will be another comparison.

Comment: However, in order to do the regression, I also need reference data that represents the relationship between sort1 and sort2 using known individuals. That's why I need to create a unique reference for every single comparison. Make sense?

Comment: what's your sessionInfo

Comment: and in layman's.  what is the desired outcome. I still am unclear on what the values represent so I'm having trouble wrapping my head around. relational datasets are big part of my day to day so sorry I'm not getting this off the bat

Comment: R version 3.3.2 on 64bit linux running through r-studio.

Each row in sort represents what I'm calling an "element". Where the element has a side, and sometimes an individual number. For elements where the individual number is the same, they come from the same individual. The other variables, H2, H2, U1, U2, etc, are metric measurements that are unique to an element. H1 and H2 are metric measurements for the Element H and so on.

I'm combining elements from the same individual to compare with every other element to predict if that element could belong to that individual based on a 90% PI.

Comment: I'm on Linux r studio server too. do you have dplyr loaded

Comment: Working on testing this now. Thanks for all your help. I'm getting this error when running all of your code:  "Error in Ops.factor(i[["Element"]], f_src$Side) : level sets of factors are different". I'll keep playing with it, but I think you are very close to having a solution.

Comment: options (stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

Comment: Combining them into a single df definitely simplifies it, but It's not quite right. Trying to figure out where the confusion is coming from. There should be 6 combinations in total but you only have 4.  I think I confused you when I said the combination cannot be the same side and element. I meant when taken together, as in a left H cannot be compared to a left H, but a left H can be compared to a left R. Also, within the df, I still need the ID and Side variables to identify the elements in the statistical results.

Edited: let me finish my morning coffee lol, I think I'm confusing myself.

Comment: I've added an edit to show a visual representation of the combinations for the sort data.

Comment: my comment didn't go through on my model image. I'll circle back on this later. we should probably move the work somewhere else like a repo haha

Comment: Yeah, that might be best lol. No rush, I have a lot of time before I need this 100% functional (literally months). It goes well above what I'm used to doing with R so its been a steep learning curve. I do appreciate the help!

Comment: Yeah,, jjlynch2